# eclipse import project not showing Git option

Tags: eclipse, git, installation

Are there any extra steps needed to have "Import Project" option show "Git" in Eclipse Menu ?

Ubuntu 16.04 - Installed Git, Installed eclipse 4.4.

Unzipped egit package (tried various versions compatible with eclipse 4.4) and verified features and plugins directory have corresponding jars copied. [I can't use update Software option as complete installation is via script]

Open eclipse - No "Git" option in import ...

Comment: Just unzipping features/plugins is not a supported way to install things and won't work in Eclipse 4 as it won't notice the changes. You must use Install New Sofware - that has an option to install from a downloaded archive.

Comment: You can use the P2 Director command line application if needed: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html?cp=2_0_20_2

Comment: Are there any reasons to use such an old Eclipse version instead of the current one with EGit built in? You are 10 releases and couple of years behind.

Comment: @howlger This is eclipse wrapper from a company, so don't have much choice and asking their plugin to work with upgraded eclipse will have wait period that i can not afford. I am going to try P2 Director as suggested  by nitind and report back.